# Unable to add value inside array field which is stored under a cloud firestore document

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've created multiple array fields under a document and I'm trying to push some value to array fields on click of button but however on button click nothing happens I've added a oncomplete listener but unfortunately it's never getting called.

Database Screen Shot

[image]

This is my class:

```
public class Itemdetails extends Fragment{

    private FirebaseFirestore db;
    TextView name,counter;
    ImageView add,del;
    ImageView img;
    Button confirm;
    int i=0;

    public static Itemdetails newInstance() {
        Itemdetails fragment = new Itemdetails();
        return fragment;
    }
    public Itemdetails() {

    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_itemdet, container, false);
        name=view.findViewById(R.id.itemname);
        img=view.findViewById(R.id.itemdetimg);
        counter=view.findViewById(R.id.counter);
        add=view.findViewById(R.id.add);
        del=view.findViewById(R.id.sub);
        confirm=view.findViewById(R.id.confirm);
        Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),  "fonts/Poppins-ExtraBoldItalic.ttf");
        name.setTypeface(custom_font);
        add.setOnClickListener(v -> counter.setText(String.valueOf(i++)));
        del.setOnClickListener(v -> counter.setText(String.valueOf(i--)));
        String url = getArguments().getString("url");
        String item = getArguments().getString("name");
        name.setText(item);
        Glide.with(getContext()).load(url).into(img);
        confirm.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            String qty=counter.getText().toString();
            if (qty.equals("0")){
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Please Specify Quantity",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {
                db=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                db.collection("Order").document("Table 1")
                        .update(
                                "items", FieldValue.arrayUnion("ABCD"),
                                "quantity", FieldValue.arrayUnion("34")
                        ).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Item Added",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

            }
            });

        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }

}
```

I've tried everything including using hashmaps, array lists but the database is never getting updated no matter whichever method I try.
Any help will be appreciated, 
Thanks.

Comment: Is your else part of your statement even triggered?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes it's getting triggered i checked that but however i tested for the problem and found that i'm unable to do any type of entries only inside the Order collection rest of the collections are getting updated properly however when i try to update Order collection nothing happens

Comment: Do you have security rules that do not allow you to write at that location?

Comment: No i don't have any rules that prevent me to do that i've set allow read ,write i.e rules are public

Comment: If you are trying to simply add a property (not to update the array), does it work?

Comment: @AlexMamo no nothing work i can't even add a simple string field nor any array inside this collection

Comment: Have you tried to add the failure listener, to see what might be the potential problem?

Comment: @AlexMamo i deleted the collection and recreated it now i'm able to create simple string fields inside the collection however previously i wasn't able to

Comment: Good to hear that, so you're now good, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes i'm good now guess deleting and recreating the collection solved the problem. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

the field names in your update call aren't matching the screenshot. The first letter in the screenshot is uppercase.

```
.update(
    "Items", FieldValue.arrayUnion("ABCD"),
    "Quantity", FieldValue.arrayUnion("34")
)
```

Comment: Still same problem after changing to uppercase nothing happens 
NOTE: I changed first letters of only Table 10 documents to uppercase for testing
However rest of the fields are all lowercase 
so this should be an issue